# How to print principal using JSF 2.0 + Facelets?

Tags: jsf, facelets, principal

with jsp I can easily print the logged in principal using: `<%= request.getUserPrincipal() %>` now I would like to do the same using JSF 2.0 + Facelets. How to do that? I have been trying for a while but no success so far.

Tx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<h:outputText value="#{request.getUserPrincipal()}" />` should work in JSF 2.0, if you want to merely display the current user.

Comment: Note that this requires EL 2.2. Better do `#{request.userPrincipal}` so that it also works on Servlet 2.5 containers. An alternative is `#{request.remoteUser}` which effectively returns the principal's name as `String`.

Comment: Hi, I will try the suggested approach and provide feedback soon. Tx for helping.