# getUserName on Facelet after Spring bsic authentication

Tags: spring, jsf

Hi I am able to get the user details on my bean using below code. But I am not able to get the user name on my page.

```
 @Controller
 @SessionScoped
 public class HomeController extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler  {
 @Override
 public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

UserDetails user = (UserDetails)auth.getPrincipal();
System.out.println("user::::"+user.getUsername());
  request.getSession().setAttribute("user",user.getUsername());

  setDefaultTargetUrl("/Home");


  super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, auth);}}
```

I am able to redirect and Now inside another controller I tried getting this userName by

```
FacesContext facesCntxt = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map sessionMap = facesCntxt.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
        String userName = (String)sessionMap.get("user");
```

till now it is working fine..but when I try to get this detail using #{param['user']} in my facelet it is not returning any value.

what is the mistake I am making?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little confusing you have an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` which is a `@Controller` and uses the JSF (or CDI) `@SessionScoped`? Which is it?

`@Controller` is a specific stereotyped `@Component` annotation used in Spring MVC, the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` is a Spring Security interface and not a Spring MVC Controller. So I would expect a `@Component` (or simply register it in XML with your Spring Security configuration).

`@SessionScoped` doesn't do anything (unless you have written an extension) in a Spring context. So you should remove it.

If you have configured Spring Security correctly the username can be obtained from the `HttpServletRequest` by simply obtaining the `Principal` with the `getUserPrincipal` method. See [How to print principal using JSF 2.0 + Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042174/how-to-print-principal-using-jsf-2-0-facelets) on how to do that. (So no need to hack around yourself, just use the standards).